# How to send a Solr spatial query using JSON request API

Tags: json, solr, spatial

What is the equivalent JSON request for querying a spatial location field in Apache Solr to:

```
&fq={!bbox sfield=locfield}&pt=45.15,-93.85&d=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `params` block.

> Parameters placed in a `params` block act as if they were added verbatim
> to the query-parameters of the request.

For example using curl :

```
curl "http://hostname:8983/solr/corename/query?" -d '
{
  params: {
    q: "*:*",
    fq: "{!bbox sfield=locfield}",
    pt: "45.15,-93.85",
    d: "5"
  }
}'
```

@see [JSON Request API Supported Properties and Syntax](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/json-request-api.html#supported-properties-and-syntax)

Comment: There's a space missing before "-d"

Comment: I fixed the typos, thanks !